# Set a timeout when the first data is received

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial

my expected codes:

```
import serial

se = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=9600, timeout=None)
recieve = []
while True:
    terima = se.read()
    terima = terima.decode('ascii')
    if terima != "":
        recieve.append(terima)
        se.timeout(2)
    if se.timeout==True:
        break
print(receive)
```

i  expect that codes can set timeout when the first data has received, so when the last data has received, it will break the 'while loop'.
but that codes given the problems :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/pi/Desktop/teserial.py", line 11, in <module>
       se.timeout(2)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: I think you want `se.timeout = 2`, but then I'm not sure what your `if se.timeout==True` line is supposed to do. Do you just want `else: break`?

Comment: @smarx no, i want if after 2 seconds has been reached (timeout) it will be break that 'while loop'.

Comment: Does `else: break` not do what you want?

Comment: @smarx ya. But this thread had resolved, sir. i found the other way to fix that codes. thanks a lot, sir.